# Default monitor on startup

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have little problem with my tripple monitor setup.
In Windows settings my TV is number one, second monitor is number two and main monitor is number three. Now, on startup BIOS, Windows logo etc is displayed on second monitor. Can I change somehow orders of monitors so that main monitor(monitor number three) is used on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally tied to the Video-Ports on your device.
Look which screen is showing the Windows Logo (#2 in your case) and connect #3 to the Port #2 was connected to.

If you have an extremely advanced BIOS, there might be a setting but don't take my word for it.

This setting can not be changed in Windows because it is tied to the BIOS. 
The "Windows Logo Screen" is still in the UEFI Bios and not it Windows

Comment: Before I reinstalled Windows displays had different order.